# unexpected behavior of java loops

Tags: java, math

I got a problem like this:-

```
A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
```

to solve the problem I wrote a program like this:

```
public void palindrome(){
        int n=0;
        for (int i = 100; i < 999; i++) { // I belive that largest palindrome is between 100 and 999
            for (int j = 100; j <999; j++) {
                n=i*j;
                if(n>100000){
                    if(n/100000==n%10){
                        if(n/10000-(n/100000)*10==(n%100)/10){
                            if(n/1000-(n/10000)*10==(n%1000)/100){
                                System.out.println(n);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

but out put is this :- 580085
if I changed the loops like this

```
for (int i = 900; i < 999; i++) { // I belive that largest palindrome is between 900 and 999
                for (int j = 900; j <999; j++) {
```

then it get the correct answer, I can not understand the behavior of this program ?
can anyone explain ?

Comment: The second version runs one hundred times faster than the first version; My hunch is that you're just not letting the code run to completion, and that it will output the correct answer if you wait long enough. Also, indent your code, please, it's very difficult to read. There may be a bug in your palindrome-checking code, which I don't feel like reasoning about right now; you could just convert it to a String `s` and check `s.equals(s.reverse())`.

Comment: Your problem is that you output all values, not just the largest. So in the first case, the last is *580085*. More details bellow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the algorithm wrong. the loop should've been something like:

```
    public void palindrome(){
    int n=0,largest=0;
    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) { // I belive that largest palindrome is between 100 and 999
        for (int j = i+1; j <=999; j++) {
            n=i*j;
            if(n>100000){
                if(n/100000==n%10){//first and last
                    if((n/10000)%10==(n%100)/10){ //second and fifth
                        if((n/1000)%10==(n%1000)/100){ //third and fourth
                            if(n>largest) largest=n;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    System.out.println(largest);
}
```

It's not that your algorithm is wrong, but I'm pretty sure it will output the same result twice. You'll see your result when i=993 and j=913 and when i=913 and j=993. But in this case, the output will be sorted by the max value of i, which won't necessarily produce the greatest product.
 Your current looping is permutation, and you need combination to solve this problem, i.e. 101*121 equals 121*101, don;t repeat the same multiplication twice.

Answer (score 3):

999*999 = 998001

580085 is less than 998001 so I don't see why you think it is an incorrect answer?

Most likely it is a correct answer and by only looping from 900 to 999 you are just removing it from the possible set by removing one or both sides of the multiplication that gives that result.

Note that for correctness you should use <= 999, not < 999 as 999 is a valid value.

Comment: I agree with you, but 580085 is not the correct answer because correct answer is 906609. and it comes only the second version of the loop

Answer (score 0):

It's probably integer overflow. Integers in Java cannot go above 2^32, and if they do they loop back around to -2^32. Using Longs is suggested for cases in which you will be dealing with large numbers (up to 2^64), or `BigInteger` if your numbers go beyond that.

Comment: but why. if you have two first 4-digit numbers and multiply them, you get 1000000 that is still within range

Answer (score 0):

As said by Tim B, after running your program I also get *580085* without the negative sign, which is a valid value.

Also, your code will output **all** palindromic values, not only the largest. In the first case your last value is *580085*

When you reduce your loop range, the last value is which is the largest *906609*

So you should check if the current calculated palindrome is largest than the latest larges.

This will give you the correct answer with both loops.